# "Words of rustic origin" like "anser"

Tags: etymology, aspiration

According to Allen in his *Vox Latina*, initial h- "was omitted...in words of rustic origin", like *anser*. No doubt *anser* originally had an initial h- (cf. Sanskrit *haṃsas*, "swan"; Greek χήν, "goose"), but interestingly, all the other examples Allen provides for words that lost the initial h- have a form attested with it except *anser*. Words like *arena*, *umor*, *aedus*, and *ircus* have amply attested forms with their initial aspirant.

I note that Cato the Elder, Plautus, Lucilius, and Hemina all attest to *anser* without an initial h-, yet nowhere in [PHI](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23hans) can you find a form with it. Is *anser* unique in this regard? Or are there other words that similarly lost that initial h- very early on? If not, what conclusions can we draw from its unique status?

Comment: I went through all the PIE lemmas on Wiktionary starting with  *\*ǵʰ-* or *\*gʰ-* and I additionally found  [*ēr*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/er#Latin) 'hedgehog' (Greek χήρ 'hedgehog' (Hesychius), χοῖρος 'porcupine'), but I've never seen that in the wild (so to speak) so it might just be very rare.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Thanks! I didn't think to look there. The word is in Plautus' *Captivi*. Though some editors prefer *ictim* instead, Codex Vetus (*B*), apparently the best of the mss., has *irim*, assuming it's an alternate form of the late Latin *eres*. That's definitely a possible answer, although its rarity and the uncertainty in the manuscripts means I can't really use it to draw too many conclusions.